# How to stop epoll_wait?

Tags: c++, epoll

I just started coding in Linux and need to port my Win server code here using `epoll`.
I can't figure out how to stop `epoll_wait`.

The epoll loop runs in separate thread(s) and the main function handles console commands. I need to stop the server after "quit" command is entered. Simply closing the master socket has no effect. So how to stop epoll correctly in this case (maybe cause somehow `epoll_wait` to return error in all threads)?

Comment: If you are exiting the application, it doesn't really matter. When the main thread exits/returns from main, the entire process (including *all* threads) will be terminated by the OS, regardless of what they are doing.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, but I want to join all running threads where the `epoll_wait` was called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you put a special file descriptor in the `epoll` list of file descriptors. An [`eventfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) or a [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) are good candidates. Whenever you need to interrupt `epoll_wait`, you signal that file descriptor and in the event handling loop you check that file descriptor as the loop exit criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could close epoll fd from another thread and fire a SIGINT which you can just ignore and then when epoll_wait restart, since efd is no longer valid, it will return -1 and set errno to EINVAL so you can exit epoll thread.

```
int efd;
pthread_t ethread;
        
void terminate_epoll( void )
{
    close( efd );
    pthread_kill( ethread, SIGINT );
    pthread_join( ethread, NULL );
}
      
void* epoll_thread( void* data )
{
    for(;;)
    {
        n = epoll_wait( efd, events, EPOLL_EVENT_COUNT, -1 );
        if( n == -1 )
        {
        if( errno == EINTR )
            continue;
        if( errno == EINVAL )
            goto end;
        ...
            
        }
    }
end:
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This solution is potentially racy, since the `efd` descriptor could be reused (e.g. by another thread), which would prevent `epoll_wait` from failing. Also, this necessarily requires signals to be not masked for the epoll thread, which may not be a good idea. You typically want to handle signals in one thread, and that thread may not be the epoll thread. If you insist on handling signals in epoll thread, you should probably use [`signalfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) instead.